# What is the connection between Ray (Geometric) optics and Electromagnetic theory optics in fiber optics?

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, geometric-optics, fiber-optics

I am currently reading about fiber optics and wave propagation in fiber optics and encountered the following part of Gerd Keiser's Book :

[image: part of book]

according to the diagram shown, its a general case when the light ray is entering the fiber optic with certain angle (not necessary longitudinal and coincides on the z axis) - like the broken rays  shown - also I know - and correct me here  - that the direction of the arrow/ray correspond to the propagation vector of the electromagnetics wave and  consequently as I imagine at any point inside the optical fiber (not necessary lateral boundary) there should be three components of the electric and magnetic field one in direction of radius Er radially out and one in the direction of Phi Ephi and the third one in the direction of z access Ez , now what confuses me in the attached screen shot the book here assumes the E and H fields to propagate in Z direction as per Equation 2.32a and 2.23b and by that ignoring Ez component (i understand E is function of r and phi because that generalize the polarization and the plane and should lie in the plane (wave front) perpendicular to z) - that confuses me more as the described assumption is ok with me regarding the wave whose ray coincides on z axis but not the general form of broken rays  , I may be misunderstanding something  , missing something so please help me understand why this assumption is ok with case of broken rays also

Edit:
My problem exactly  is Why the assumption of ignoring Ez , the z component of electric field is done , same for magnetic field in equations 2.32a and 2.32b

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.